# Como hacer un flexbox strech y center al mismo tiempo

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
actualmente tengo un flexbox que contiene estas tarjetitas por asi decir y quiero que ademas de tener la propiedad strech para que pueden haber mas de una por linea tambien quiero que se queden centradas y que asi no se vea feo, pero no consigo hacerlo, ¿alguien sabe la solucion?
actualmente tengo esto:

```css
.cards{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 4;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
}

.cards .card{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    align-self: center;
}

/*Ik this code is probably weird*/
```

```html
<div class="cards">
      <div class="card"> this is my 1st card</div>
      <div class="card"> this is A card</div>
      <div class="card"> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      <div class="card"> this is my 4th card</div>
</div>
```

html y css(ya esta en el snippet):

```
<div class="cards">
      <div class="card"> this is my 1st card</div>
      <div class="card"> this is A card</div>
      <div class="card"> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      <div class="card"> this is my 4th card</div>
</div>
```

```
.cards{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 4;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
}

.cards .card{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    align-self: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para centrarlo, te falta la propiedad ***justify-content***, que define cómo se distribuye el espacio en el eje principal definido por ***flex-direction*** (horizontal para *row* y *row-reverse*, vertical para *column* y *column-reverse*).

Dependiendo de la forma en la que quieras que se distribuya, añade a la clase del contenedor (.cards) el atributo con alguno de los valores de los que dispone. Para lo que quieres hacer, el valor *space-around* seguramente sea el más apropiado, pero también podrías probar con *space-between* o *center*.

Tienes más información aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

```
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 4;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
}
```